# Two bugs with Keyboard Shortcuts: confirmation and/or solutions requested

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, macbook, bug-reporting

I have 2 bugs in my Ubuntu 12.04 fresh installation using a Macbook Pro keyboard. Note: I swapped the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> on regular keyboards), but that should not affect the shortcuts I program.)

### First

**I changed the `Switch application` shortcut from <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.** It saves this correctly but the change does not seem to take effect. I rebooted and it still doesn't. **<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> stays working and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> does nothing**. I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> is used by the Chromium browser, but outside the browser the shortcut isn't working either.
Can anyone confirm this? I changed another shortcut in the `Navigation` section but this change isn't working either.

### Second

In the `Windows` section, I want to change the shortcut for `Close window` from <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> (as it is in Mac and because the Function keys can only be used together with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key). For some reason in some application through Ubuntu's defaults the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut is programmed for closing windows already (although only a few) but it seems that in the System Settings it is as well. So when I click the `Close window` item and want to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> as a new shortcut it closes the window. **I cannot set the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> hotkey anywhere since it closes the Shortcuts window as I type it.**

Can anyone using a regular keyboard confirm any of these 2 bugs? Does anyone know a solution for them? Anyone knows if these bugs are already filed? If not I will look for them and file them myself, but I just wanted some feedback first.

Answer (score 0):

Till this date I have seen most of the program using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> for iterating through opened tab panes,and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the presently active tabbed pane.

Now what you are expecting is closing the application i.e. overriding the default to act on whole application rather than the internal child contents in both the cases.

So marking them as bug wont be right as they are doing what has been assigned to them, but your experiment is creating conflict for them.Right now I am not using ubuntu 12 otherwise must have suggested you some workaround. :)

Comment: In fact, only few applications use the Ctrl-W shortcut. They all seem to require Ctrl-Q to close windows. And it's no problem that those shortcuts are overridden by some applications, those mostly already use them in the way I want, as you state. F.e. VLC player requires Ctrl-Q to close a video window (also when >=2 are present). Terminal doesn't react to either of them.

Comment: You are right, but as a programmer I dont have to take pain for writing handling code for shortcuts like Alt+F4 or Ctrl+W, but it really requires effort for ctrl+Q.You can understand what am I trying to say. :)

Comment: In Mac Ctrl-W is a built-in shortcut for closing windows in an app while Ctrl-Q is also built-in for closing whole apps.